# Color issues with OpenCV when migrated from Webcam to Raspicam

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, raspberry-pi

I am trying to develop an application using OpenCV. I got a Raspberry Pi Camera 3 (Raspicam 3) now. I am trying to migrate my code from standart version with Webcam to Raspicam version using the API found at https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40.

What I did is simply convert:

```
cv::Mat image;

VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera

cap >> image;

cap.release();
```

into

```
cv::Mat image;

raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );

Camera.grab();
Camera.retrieve ( image);

Camera.release();
```

Now the photo I took has really weird colors (seems like inverted) when I try to see it with

```
cv::imwrite("myimg.jpg",image);
```

The difference I notice is that raspberry pi camera API sets this value:

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
```

However this value causes program to crash,

[image]

so I either use

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3 );
```

or

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_BGR2HSV );
```

Then, it does not crash but the colors are weird looking. (e.g. Orange is blue)

The question is, how do I prevent this color change? How do I set up camera with right parameters so that it takes a normal photo?

I should let you know that I dont know OpenCV in detail, just trying to figure these things out.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Cheers,

**EDIT:**
When I comment the line

```
Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC1 );
```

Everything is also blue-ish. So I guess it does not have anything to do with it.

**EDIT:** Added error details.

Comment: `Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_BGR2HSV );` -- That's pretty obviously wrong, `CV_BGR2HSV` being a colour conversion code, not a data type. `CV_8UC1` most likely fails, since the camera is still capturing 3 channel images and you try to fit them into a single channel matrix. (BTW, "causes program to crash" is a damn poor description of the issue.) | As @SachaVakili hints at, a simple `cvtColor` doing BGR2RGB (or vice versa) will probably fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the color space of your Raspberry Pi is the same as Open CV?

Open CV uses the Blue Green Red (BGR) convention, which is not that frequent. It might correspond to your "blue-ish" description...

If so, just swap the first and last channels to get RGB values :)